# Why Magento 1 allows two customers with the same data?

Tags: customer-account

I created a customer account directly in Backend based on a phone conversation. Over a while I discovered there is an account with the same data created a year ago by the customer.

I would like to ask:

- Why Magento 1 allows two customers with the same data? Why I was not warned by Magento there is already a customer with that email address?
- Where will go the orders created by the customer, to ID 3 or 4?
- Where will go the orders created in Backend using the account created by administrator, to ID 3 or 4? As I see even I am using this account there are no orders associated to it, all orders will go to account with ID 4.

I recreated this behavior in a test environment and see the image bellow. Two customers with the same data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a configuration setting "Share Customer Accounts" that can be set to "Per Website" or "Global". If it is set to "Per Website", each website has its own customer database (not technically, but conceptually), so that users have to register at each website separately.

As you can see in the highlighted area of your screenshot, "admin" is treated as a separate website. So the account that you created is not usable from the frontend, it's just for the "admin website".

Comment: I appreciate for your comment. When I am using in Backend the customer with Admin tag to create an order, I have to select a Website. If I am selecting English it will generate a conflict with the other account. This account is only for Admin website and I don't understand well its purpose. I cannot do anything with it like placing orders. To avoid such of issues related to the same customer data from the very beginning I should set that option you mentioned.